# How to host wordpress instance as sub-directory URL when it's hosted on a separate server to the main site?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns, reverse-proxy

Given I have two separate EC2 instances:

**35.0.0.1** - this one runs a web application for the main site

**35.0.0.2** - this one runs the wordpress blog

How do I set up DNS and/or reverse proxies so that:

**example.com** - will load the web app from the first server

**example.com/blog(*?)** - will render pages from the WP instance on the second server

If it matters, server 1 uses nginx and server 2 uses Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using reverse proxy. Since you have nginx installed at server 1 
You can configure the server 2 as backend for the reverse proxy on server 1 for `/blog` uri.

And let your DNS point to server 1 for your domain example.com.

Config for backend and proxy setup for /blog in nginx-

```
upstream blog{
  server 35.0.0.2 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
}



location /blog/ {
     proxy_pass http://blog;
}
```